# How to define the sort order of clusters in GraphViz?

Tags: layout, graph, graphviz

I wrote a script that dynamically generates graphviz graphs, containing some clusters.
I'd like to define the sort order of clusters, since when I visualize the graph, clusters are not always in the same order I defined them.

I tried to use "packmode" and "sortv" attributes, but maybe I understand bad their use. Here is a simple exameple, where I would like to have the cluster B on left, and cluster A on right:

```
digraph G {

    pack=true;
    packmode="array_u";

subgraph cluster_A {
    sortv=2;

    node [label="A1"] A1;
    node [label="A2"] A2;
    node [label="A3"] A3;

    A1->A2;
    A1->A3;
}

subgraph cluster_B {
    sortv=1;

    node [label="B1"] B1;
    node [label="B2"] B2;
    node [label="B3"] B3;

    B1->B2;
    B1->B3;
}

B1->A1 [constraint="false"];
}
```

How can I solve this trouble? Tnanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect, but if you draw an invisible edge from cluster B to cluster A, it will place cluster B as a predecessor of cluster A, but a bit above:

```
digraph G {

    pack=true;
    packmode="array_u";

    compound = "true";

subgraph cluster_A {
    sortv=2;

    node [label="A1"] A1;
    node [label="A2"] A2;
    node [label="A3"] A3;

    A1->A2;
    A1->A3;
}

subgraph cluster_B {
    sortv=1;

    node [label="B1"] B1;
    node [label="B2"] B2;
    node [label="B3"] B3;

    B1->B2;
    B1->B3;
}

B1->A1 [constraint="false"];

B1 -> A1
[
    ltail = "cluster_B"
    lhead = "cluster_A"
    style = "invis"
]

}
```

Just add the `compound=true` instruction and the invisible edge.

Comment: If you skip the `pack=true` option, you can use `newrank=true` and then `{rank=same; A1 B1}`. They are then placed next to one another